# Is there a newer version of the module php5-redis for ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, redis, owncloud

I installed `owncloud` (v 10.0.3.3) in my server (`Ubuntu 16.04`) and I try to resolve an warning I get about:

> Transactional file locking should be configured to use memory-based
>   locking, not the default slow database-based locking. See the
>   [documentation ↗](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/go.php?to=admin-transactional-locking) for more information.

I followed this guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04) and I installed Redis successfully to listen on unix socket.

```
 sudo systemctl status redis
● redis.service - Redis In-Memory Data Store
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/redis.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-10-19 08:37:37 UTC; 25min ago
 Main PID: 1034 (redis-server)
    Tasks: 4
   Memory: 2.5M
      CPU: 2.393s
   CGroup: /system.slice/redis.service
           └─1034 /usr/local/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:0

Oct 19 08:37:37 myserver redis-server[1034]:   `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
Oct 19 08:37:37 myserver redis-server[1034]:  |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
Oct 19 08:37:37 myserver redis-server[1034]:  |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
Oct 19 08:37:37 myserver redis-server[1034]:   `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
Oct 19 08:37:37 myserver redis-server[1034]:       `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'
Oct 19 08:37:37 myserver redis-server[1034]:           `-._        _.-'
Oct 19 08:37:37 myserver redis-server[1034]:               `-.__.-'
Oct 19 08:37:37 myserver redis-server[1034]: 1034:M 19 Oct 08:37:37.818 # Server initialized
Oct 19 08:37:37 myserver redis-server[1034]: 1034:M 19 Oct 08:37:37.822 * DB loaded from disk: 0.004 seconds
Oct 19 08:37:37 myserver redis-server[1034]: 1034:M 19 Oct 08:37:37.823 * The server is now ready to accept connections at /tmp/redis.sock
```

Back to the owncloud `config.php` when I add the line `'memcache.locking' => '\OC\Memcache\Redis'` I get the message in the browser:

> Memcache \OC\Memcache\Redis not available for local cache Is the
>   matching PHP module installed and enabled?

I tried to install `php5-redis` but the package can't not be located.

Is there a newer version of this module compatible with php7?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I installed this php module by:

```
sudo apt install php-redis
```

and it worked...